# How to crop out part of date range in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot some data over time. However, data is missing for a large part of the time series. I'd like to remove the whole section with missing data from the middle of the graph.

Here's the data

```
# Setup 
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Set seed 
set.seed(123)

# Generate data
df_test <- 
  tibble(
    date = seq(as.Date("2010-1-1"), as.Date("2015-1-1"), by = "months"),
    value = rnorm(n = length(date), mean = 10, sd = 1)) %>% 
  mutate( # Create missing values
    value = ifelse(
      date > as.Date("2010-03-20") & date < as.Date("2011-01-14"), 
      NA, 
      value))
```

Here's the graph with no cropping

```
# Graph full range
gg_full <- 
  df_test %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = date, 
      y = value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_step()
```

[image]

I want to remove the dates with missing values from the x-axis. Here's a photoshop with "-//-" where I've excised the dates.

[image]

**Attempted solution**

I tried creating two separate graphs and plot them side by side with patchwork.

```
# Graph first part only
gg_first <- 
  df_test %>%
  filter(date <= as.Date("2010-03-20")) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = date, 
      y = value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_step()

# Graph latter part only
gg_latter <- 
  df_test %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date("2011-01-14")) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = date, 
      y = value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_step()

# Layout plots 
gg_first + gg_latter + 
  patchwork::plot_layout(widths = c(1, 6))
```

[image]

However, this messes up the x-axis scale and involves a lot of manually removing elements like the y-axis labels from the right-hand but not the left-hand graph. However, I might simply be failing to use patchwork to its full potential.

Comment: This is not made easy in `ggplot2`, maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077866/force-y-axis-to-start-at-0-insert-break-and-have-a-large-y-axis-using-ggplot

Comment: Buried there is this blog 

https://www.j4s8.de/post/2018-01-15-broken-axis-with-ggplot2/

Which uses facet_grid to create the break and it works really well. 

df_test %<>% 
  mutate(
    facet_indicator = case_when(
      date <= as.Date("2010-03-20") ~ "First", 
      date >= as.Date("2011-01-14") ~ "Latter",
      TRUE ~ "Excise"))

And then you run

df_test %>% 
  filter(facet_indicator != "Excise") %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      date, 
      value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_step() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ facet_indicator) 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `ggbreak`:

```r
library(ggbreak)
gg_full +
  scale_x_break(c(ymd("2010-03-25"), ymd("2011-01-10"))) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x.top = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this works thanks :) We can tidy up the x-axis with 

gg_full +
  ggbreak::scale_x_break(
    breaks = as.Date(c("2010-03-21", "2011-01-01"))) + 
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "1 year",
    date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x.top = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x.top = element_blank())

Comment: Very much cleaner indeed. Do you mind if I add to the answer?

Comment: Go for it, the better for posterity