# How to add a mark in an axis break using ggbreak?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggbreak

I'd like to add a mark to notify the break in my axis as in the graph below.

[image: Example break mark in axis]

By using the dataset iris, here is the code.

```r
p <-
 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.y.right = element_blank(),
  ) +
  scale_y_break(c(4.5, 5.0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))
```

How can I add something to notify the break in the axis as in the image above?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I used the dataset 'iris' to get a reproducible example. I hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61082435/3460670) as well as the [ggh4x package](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x)